# Stored procedure to rename other stored procedure!

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, rename

I'm using SQL Server and I've been developing a stored procedure to rename (actually, add a prefix in its name) other stored procedures. I have been trying to do this but I don't know why I'm getting this error.

Take a look at my code:

```
DECLARE @_currentProcedure AS VARCHAR(300)
DECLARE @_newProcedure AS VARCHAR(300)

SET @_currentProcedure = '[dbo].[' + @ProcedureName + ']'
SET @_newProcedure = @Prefx + @ProcedureName 

-- check if this procedure exists
IF (EXISTS(SELECT * 
           FROM [dbo].[sysobjects] 
           WHERE ID = object_id(@_currentProcedure ) 
              AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1
         )) 
BEGIN
        -- rename it (doesn't work)
        EXEC sp_rename @_currentProcedure , @_newProcedure , 'OBJECT'
        GO

END
```

And when I try to compile this, I get a error saying

> Wrong syntax near 'OBJECT'
>   Wrong syntax near 'END'

Something like this.

What can I do to fix this error and make this procedure works!?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well that `GO` should be at end .. that is it should be

```
BEGIN 
EXEC sp_rename @_currentProcedure , @_newProcedure , 'OBJECT'  
END
GO
```

Comment: I get GO command out the procedure and now It's working. Thank you Rahul!

Answer (score 0):

_newProcedure is set from @Procedure name, so it is missing the brackets and the `dbo.` that you've added to _currentProcedure.

Try:

```
 SET @_newProcedure = '[dbo].[' + @Prefx + @ProcedureName + ']'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help too Mark! But my procedure wasn't compiling! Now it's working! Thanks!